# Does anyone have any links to some great UX for 'app setup' pages?

Tags: website-design, web-app

I've taken over a large scale project and revamped how the whole system works. But one issue we have is a 'not-so-user-friendly' set-up page for the app.

I was wondering if anyone has any links to a place where I can see examples of good 'setup pages'

We've got text inputs for information, graphic upload functionality and the like, but I'd like to make it... "look easier to use"

Comment: If you can figure out what "looks easier to use" means, half your work is done

Comment: I'm just looking for some inspiration. Recoding the project was tiring enough - I'd like some inspiration on designing the back end of it

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend performing a search on [Dribbble (www.dribbble.com)](http://www.dribbble.com).  Though its primary purpose is to showcase beautiful graphic design, I have found a lot of great UI inspiration there.

Specifically, you might try the following searches:

- http://dribbble.com/search?q=setup
- http://dribbble.com/search?q=configure
- http://dribbble.com/search?q=configuration
- http://dribbble.com/search?q=account
- http://dribbble.com/search?q=settings

Alternately, you can check out [Pattern Tap (www.patterntap.com)](http://www.patterntap.com), which is intended more for UI inspiration but has fewer submissions to-date.

Answer (score 4):

Like David said, Dribble is a great source for any inspiration, but there are a couple of other pattern websites that have what you're looking for.

Mobile Patterns: http://www.mobile-patterns.com/sign-up-flows/ (some good examples)
UI Patterns: http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Tour (an essay + examples)

Going to add [UX Archive](http://uxarchive.com/) as well.

Hope those helped!